# GLS REML vs. ML and comparison to LM

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have been reading up on nmle::gls and it seems method = "REML" should be preferred to get more accurate estimates. Using method = REML is also equivalent to lm when no correlation structure is specified.

However, I was surprised as the 95% confidence intervals of gls using REML are not the same as those obtained using lm - instead gls with REML and ML produce equivalent results.

What am I missing? why can't I replicate the LM results with gls with REML?

```
library(nlme)

data(iris)

gls.ml = nlme::gls(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris, method = "ML")
gls.reml = nlme::gls(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris, method = "REML")
lm = lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)
```

GLS with ML

```
Generalized least squares fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length 
  Data: iris 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -43.59109 -34.55919 24.79555

Coefficients:
                  Value  Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept)  -0.3630755 0.03976199 -9.13122       0
Petal.Length  0.4157554 0.00958244 43.38724       0

 Correlation: 
             (Intr)
Petal.Length -0.906

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.75546603 -0.60252248 -0.09254885  0.64784842  3.13365662 

Residual standard error: 0.2051032 
Degrees of freedom: 150 total; 148 residual
> confint(gls.ml)
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)  -0.4410076 -0.2851435
Petal.Length  0.3969742  0.4345366
```

GLS with REML

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length 
  Data: iris 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -29.79205 -20.80041 17.89602

Coefficients:
                  Value  Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept)  -0.3630755 0.03976199 -9.13122       0
Petal.Length  0.4157554 0.00958244 43.38724       0

 Correlation: 
             (Intr)
Petal.Length -0.906

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.73703461 -0.59849218 -0.09192978  0.64351494  3.11269547 

Residual standard error: 0.2064843 
Degrees of freedom: 150 total; 148 residual
> confint(gls.reml)
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)  -0.4410076 -0.2851435
Petal.Length  0.3969742  0.4345366
```

LM

```
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.56515 -0.12358 -0.01898  0.13288  0.64272 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.363076   0.039762  -9.131  4.7e-16 ***
Petal.Length  0.415755   0.009582  43.387  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2065 on 148 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9271,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9266 
F-statistic:  1882 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> confint(lm)
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)  -0.4416501 -0.2845010
Petal.Length  0.3968193  0.4346915
```

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** the main difference is that `confint.lm()` uses a t-distribution to compute CIs while `confint.default` (used by `gls`) uses a Gaussian ...

The greater accuracy (more precisely, lower *bias* of the REML estimation only applies to estimation of variances, not of fixed effects. When you're fitting a simple linear model (no correlation structures etc.), the only real difference between ML and REML estimation is in how the residual variance is estimated.  With REML, the variance is based on the residual sum of squares divided by `N-p` (where `N` is the number of observations (here `N=150`) and `p` is the number of parameters (`p=2`). This is the same rule used by `lm`:

```r
all.equal(sigma(gls.reml), sigma(lm))  ## TRUE
```

For `ML`, the RSS is divided by `N`, so the difference in the standard deviations (returned by `sigma`) is a factor of `sqrt((N-p)/N)`

```r
all.equal(sigma(gls.ml), sigma(lm)*sqrt(148/150))  ## TRUE
```

The difference is pretty small here - about 1.4% - so there should be a *slight* difference in the confidence intervals.

**However**, this difference in the estimated residual SDs does *not* appear to affect in the computation of confidence intervals.  There is no special method for `gls` objects (see `methods("confint")`), so the default `confint()` method (`confint.default`) is used. This in turn calls the `vcov()` method (`nlme:::vcov.gls`), which extracts the $varBeta element. Looking at the code, however, `gls` explicitly reverses the REML correction when computing the covariance matrix of the fixed-effect parameters:

```r
    attr(parAssign, "varBetaFact") <- varBeta <- glsFit$sigma * 
        glsFit$varBeta * sqrt((N - REML * p)/(N - p))
    varBeta <- crossprod(varBeta)
```

I'm not sure, but I think this is intentional — it seems slightly deep to decide whether the confidence intervals of the fixed effects should be scaled according to `RSS/N` or `RSS/(N-p)` ...

The covariance matrices for the LM/ML/REML are almost identical (relative difference about 4e-16). As stated in the **tl;dr** at the beginning, the main difference between the confidence intervals is that `stats::confint.lm` uses a t-distribution while `stats::confint.default` (used by `gls`) uses a Gaussian ...

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Am I correct in thinking that REML is better used when various correlation structures are compared while ML should be used to compare different models (linear vs. quadratic) when using gls?

Comment: Yes. You should **never** use REML to compare models whose fixed effects differ. In the case of `gls` I don't think it will actually make any difference, but for mixed models it will give you garbage.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I would like to check if I should use REML rather than ML when comparing a gls model with corARMA(p = 1) vs. one with corARMA(p = 1, q = 1). I find mixed examples...

Comment: This now brings me to wonder if that also explains why the p-values I obtain from the regression: gls.reml = nlme::gls(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris, method = "REML") are not the same as if I were to estimate them manually: 

(coef=gls.reml$coef)
(pvalue<-(1-pnorm(abs(coef)/sqrt(diag(vcov(gls.reml)))))*2)

Can anyone help?

Comment: @Francesca, can you please post that as a new question, linking to this one?